# OpenMPI compilation error

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, mpi, openmpi

I have some *.cpp file which using OpenMPI. Also I have *.h file with specified to me functions (some of them) and implementation of them:

```
void Show(std::string s);
void ShowLine(std::string s);
void MPI_Output();
```

So I use these functions in my *.cpp file for example:

```
/*...*/
MPI_Output();
```

And including this header:

```
#include "my_h.h"
```

Then I'm trying to compile my frogram with `mpicc`:

```
mpicc -w my_best_program.cpp
```

It fails while in compilation process with following message:

```
/tmp/icpcBCoxCA.o: In function `main':
MPIDebug9.cpp:(.text+0xa46): undefined reference to `ShowLine(std::string)'
MPIDebug9.cpp:(.text+0xa90): undefined reference to `MPI_Output()'
MPIDebug9.cpp:(.text+0xc0f): undefined reference to `Show(std::string)'
/tmp/icpcBCoxCA.o: In function `info_main(double)':
MPIDebug9.cpp:(.text+0xe49): undefined reference to `Show(std::string)'
/tmp/icpcBCoxCA.o: In function `info(double)':
MPIDebug9.cpp:(.text+0x104e): undefined reference to `ShowLine(std::string)'
```

In addition, some info:

```
mpicc --showme:compile
-I/usr/mpi/intel/openmpi-1.4.4/include -pthread
```

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't having problem during compilation, but during linkage.

`mpicc -w my_best_program.cpp my_cpp_file_with_showline.cpp` is something you need.

Explanation: (simplified)

In .h file, there is only information "Hey, compiler, there exist some method that is called `Show`, returns `void`, and wants parameter of type `std::string`. When you are compiling cpp file that calls this function, be sure it passes it correct parameters, but it will be provided in another .cpp file. (But I'm not telling you in which one. Just look at all of them and find appropriate one)"

It does the same for all of the separate .cpp files (creating .o files - your `my_best_program.cpp` contains something like: "There is `info_main(double)` function, that has some code, and it needs to call `Show(std::string)` - called Unresolved reference".

The my_cpp_file_with_showline.cpp will create .o with "There is `Show(std::string)` method, that does something else".

And, during linkage (that is invisible for you at this moment), all of the "Unresolved references" are resolved - meaning, the `info_main(double)` will call `Show(std::string)` from different cpp file.

When you call some C++ compiler from command line with multiple cpps, it usually compiles them separately (each one has no knowledge about another, just function declarations in .h files) and then links (merges all the function calls and given functions together) into executable.

Comment: I need to specify *.cpp file with implementation of my functions?

UPD Okay, I successfully compiled my program with your solution.